# Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks

It looks like a common problem but I can't solve it. I'm using React, TypeScript and Material-UI. All together do not work if I'm using classes (that's what TS is for). Here is my minimal example that is not working:
File RTaskForm.tsx

```
import * as React from "react"
import {Task, TaskProcessor} from "./Task"
import { makeStyles, Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'


const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200,
  },
}));


export class RTaskForm extends React.Component<
    {prefix: string},
    {task: Task}> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          task: TaskProcessor.tasks(false)[1]
        }
    }

    render() {
        const classes = styles()
        return (
            <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                        <TextField
                            required
                            id="filled-required"
                            label="Required"
                            defaultValue="Hello World"
                            className={classes.textField}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="filled"
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

File index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { RTaskForm } from "./RTaskForm" 

ReactDOM.render(<div id="root">
        <RTaskForm prefix="Hi"/>
    </div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

File Task.ts (only two classes to allow compiling)

```
export class Task extends Map<string, string> {
    static emptyTask() {
        return new Task()
    }
}


export class TaskProcessor {
    static tasks(b: boolean): Task[] {
        return [Task.emptyTask()]
    }
}
```

I know I have to use withStyles instead of makeStyles, but I have to provide a function parameter for theme, null is not accepted.

Happy to get some help, thanks.

Edit: In the browser I get this error message (line 36 marked):

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See "cannot write the link here" for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

3 stack frames were collapsed.

render

src/RTaskForm.tsx:36

  33 |  }

  34 | 

  35 |  render() {

 36 |      const classes = styles()

     | ^  37 |      return (

  38 |          <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">

  39 |              <Grid container spacing={2}>

View compiled
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Is there an exception? Can you include the error output?

Comment: You can't use hooks with Class components. Either extract representation part to a functional component or use `withStyles` HOC.

Comment: I'd like to use `withStyles` but it needs a parameter when calling `const classes = styles()`.

Comment: To add to that, you can certainly use TypeScript with function components if you're saying you're using classes because of Typescript.

Comment: I'd like to use the state management inside the class because it feels the most natural way to render and modify inside the same class.

Comment: You can still use state in function components using the useState hook. React has changed quite a bit since the later releases. It may be a good idea to go back to their documentation and learn about how to use the different hooks because third party components are going to be showing up with them and you won't be able to use them with class components.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try and the third party components are a good point.